# Setting up clients based on the different clients

Tags: apache-2.2

I want to restrict the acess based on the ip address of the client.
I have different url each client they should access.

Should I say

```
<VirtualHost client1:443> 
</VirtualHost> 
<VirtualHost client12:443>
</VirtualHost> 
<VirtualHost client3:443>
</VirtualHost>
```

thanks for you help in advance

Answer (score 2):

No, the IP:Port mapping specified in the VirtualHost block is the IP address on **your server** that this vhost will be served from, not the client's IP address.

To restrict access based on client IP, use mod_access rules, either in your VirtualHost stanza or via `.htaccess` files.

For instance:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 192.168.111.222
```

More details [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html).

Comment: Avoid using .htaccess files when possible and instead do the config in the main httpd.conf. Since apache will check the .htaccess file for changes continually, using it will decrease the server performance.

Comment: @JennyD - I'd be impressed if you could demonstrate this *actually* decreasing performance. For frequently-used sites, this file will remain in the kernel read cache, meaning access to it (in RAM) may add a single millisecond to the request. Hardly anything to be concerned about.

Comment: If there is only one .htaccess file on the system - yes. But as this is Serverfault, not Superuser, I'm considering larger systems than that.